# In command prompt, how do you automatically jump to the path of a folder you searched for

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

In Windows CMD, if I search for a folder using

```
dir /s /b folder_name
```

I would then be able to go to that folder by doing

```
CD path_I_got_above
```

where I would copy-paste the path I got from the search. Is there any command I can use so that it automatically 'jump' to whatever path I got from the search?

---

I would like to jump to the first path if there were multiple paths given.

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate: [Search-and-go in Windows CMD](https://superuser.com/q/785807/241386)

Comment: nevermind, I finally got it: `For /F %A in ('dir /s /b file_name') do cd %A` and if you wanted to create an alias using doskey: `doskey search=For /F %A in ('dir /s /b $*') do cd %A`